# Creating summary report from multiple fields from a set of data

Tags: mysql

I have a task to write an sql to summarize the following data:

```
select 
payment,
status, 
interest,
principal
from payment
```

---

```
payment status  interest    principal
1       A       100         0
2       r       0           500
3       o       0           400
4       d       0           100
5       A       0           200
6       A       200         0
7       A       300         0
8       A       0           300
```

- a payment relating to interest would be where interest is not 0
- a payment relating to principal would be where a principal is not 0
- the data would need to be split into type

The result I am looking for is similar to this:

```
                 Interest total count           principal total count
Status - A              3                            1
Other                   0                            4
total of all payments   3                            5
```

I  have been using group function but have not been able to group beyond the interest amount. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify how the example data should be summarized in that pivot table?  For instance, your example data has 5 records with Status=A.  Shouldn't that equate to your "Status-A" row having a total of 5, if we add the values under 'Interest total count' and 'principal total count'

Comment: Status of A  represents the number of payments approved and other is consider not yet approved. Ultimately, I will use this pivoted data to calculate total % of approved payments in Ireport. For example. Principal payment will equate to 20% of all principal payment created. Currently, I have been able to count these payments in ireport but the performance is extremely slow in generating the results with all the counts of interest and principal payments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use `GROUP BY` + `WITH ROLLUP` for this. Something like:

```
SELECT
    IF(`status` = 'A', 'Status A', 'Others') as `-`,
    SUM(`interest` > 0) as `Interest total count`,
    SUM(`principal` > 0) as `principal total count`
FROM
    (
        SELECT 1 as `payment`, 'A' as `status`, 100 as `interest`, 0 as `principal`
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'r', 0, 500
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, 'o', 0, 400
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4, 'd', 0, 100
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 5, 'A', 0, 200
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 6, 'A', 200, 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 7, 'A', 300, 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 8, 'A', 0, 300
    ) as `sub`
GROUP BY 1 WITH ROLLUP;
```

*Result:*

```
-       Interest total count    principal total count
Others          0                       3
Status A        3                       2
                3                       5
```

*Query:*

```
SELECT
    IF(`status` = 'A', 'Status A', 'Others') as `-`,
    SUM(`interest` > 0) as `Interest total count`,
    SUM(`principal` > 0) as `principal total count`
FROM
    `payment`
GROUP BY 1 WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Thank you! I am will look into group by rollup and see if I can achieve the needed results.

Comment: @ThucNguyen If any answer on StackOverflow helped to solve your issue, then please consider to upvote it, or check as the solution. Glad to help. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @CORRUPT. This helped get the summary I needed.